# Multiples datos en variables del where en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Bueno les cuento un poco. Tengo una consulta en SQL como la siguiente >

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA
WHERE 
Priority <> 'P1'
AND Region = ISNULL(@Region,Region) 
AND PM_Name = ISNULL(@PM,PM_Name)
AND Priority = ISNULL(@Priority, Priority)
AND Status = ISNULL (@Status, Status)
```

Cada condición con @ contiene solo 1 valor, que desde la interfaz se seleccionan desde un , el problema empieza cuando me piden cambiar el select a select-multiple.
Entonces ahora puedo tener mas de un valor en cada select.

Hasta ahora la forma en como obtengo los datos del select es en una cadena por ejemplo

```
cadena = "UNO, DOS, TRES"
```

Al momento de hacer el Select en SQL como podría utilizar estos tres valores para hacer el filtrado de la información.
No se si me di a explicar bien, pero cualquier cosa lo vemos.

Los parametros a SQL los enviaba de la siguiente manera
en JS

```
 params.PM_Name = $("#cb_ProductM option:selected").text(); //nombre del action result
 params.Priority = $("#cb_Priority option:selected").text();
 params.Status = $("#cb_Status option:selected").text();
```

y los recibia en la tabla

```
<table id="datatable-GeneralTable" data-toggle="table"
                                                   data-url="@Url.Action("LoadGeneral", "Home")"
                                                   data-method="GET"
                                                   data-pagination="true"                                                                                      
data-query-params="queryParams"
                                                       data-buttons-class="primary">
```

y el action result:

```
var list = ex.Proc_CargarTabla(Region, PM_Name, Priority, Status).ToList();
```

Comment: qué versión de SQL Server estás usando?. Pasar datos como un string con comas para un filtro es algo no trivial de hacer

Comment: Muestra como mandas los datos tambien, a ver que conviene hacer del lado de quien pide los datos. Tambien, aclara el tipo de dato de los @

Comment: La version es SQL 2008, los datos los tengo @NVARCHAR, los enviaba  con el data-query-params. y asi como string los mandaba al actionresult para ejecutar el sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez, podrías crear una función tabular para retornar los datos y utilizar la siguiente lógica:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnCommaStringToTable
(   
    @Texto VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
RETURNS 
@TablaRetorno TABLE 
(
    [Dato] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @t TABLE( ID INT IDENTITY, data VARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @t(data) SELECT @Texto  

    INSERT INTO @TablaRetorno
    SELECT  
     O.splitdata 
    FROM
     (
     SELECT *,
     cast('<X>'+replace(F.data,',','</X><X>')+'</X>' as XML) as xmlfilter from @t F
     )F1
     CROSS APPLY
     ( 
     SELECT fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as splitdata 
     FROM f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)) O

     RETURN
END
GO


select * from fnCommaStringToTable('UNO, DOS, TRES')

select * from fnCommaStringToTable('UNO')
```

Lo anterior basicamente toma un string separado por comas y lo convierte en una lineas de una tabla, entonces podrías utilizarla luego en tu consulta principal (la que tienes en el ejemplo que pusiste) wheres para las condiciones puedes utilizar **CROSS APPLY** para anidar la consulta o también utilizar IN por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA
WHERE 
Priority <> 'P1'
AND CAST(Region as VARCHAR(MAX)) IN(select dato from fnCommaStringToTable(ISNULL(@Region,Region))) 
...
```

Comment: excelente, lo que buscaba! tu respuesta me ayudo a hacer lo que necesitaba! gracias!

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server te permite crear tipos de datos, usando el ejemplo de las regiones podrías crear este tipo de datos:

```
 CREATE TYPE [dbo].[REGIONS] AS TABLE(
[REGION] [varchar](100) 
)
```

La idea es poder enviar una tabla como parámetro, el SP que utilizas en tu consulta recibe el parámetro así:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NOMBRE_DEL_SP]
     @REGION REGIONS READONLY --IMPORTANTE DEJAR EL READONLY
 AS
 BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM TABLA
       WHERE 
       Priority <> 'P1'
       AND Region IN (SELECT REGION FROM @REGION)
 END
```

Para resumir el tipo de datos 'REGIONS' se comporta como una tabla que puedes llenar desde tu código y enviarla.

He usado en varias ocasiones estos tipos de de datos desde C# y le envío un dataTable al SP, en el caso de JS prefiero no dar ideas porque no es mi fuerte, pero buscando puedes conseguir como hacerlo.

Suerte

Comment: y el desempeno con mas de un usuario, me eliminaría la tabla y crearía otra no? o no hay problema si dos usuarios consultan diferente info al mismo tiempo

Comment: No es una tabla física, es una variable, por lo que no afecta la cantidad de usuarios que utilicen el sistema, cada uno trabajará con sus variables. En cuanto al desempeño, es mas eficiente que cortar cadenas de texto. saludos.